# Django Rest Framework - Give Serializer of default User model validations that mimic the default validations

Tags: python, django, rest, validation, frameworks

I am currently making a REST API that people can register themselves via. And I am just about to write the validations for how long/complex passwords should be etc. when it occurred to me there maybe is a way to mimic the default constraints that the model have set already? Is there?

My code for serializer.py looks like the following:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse

User = get_user_model()

class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    links = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password', 'groups', 'user_permissions', 'is_staff', 'is_active', 'is_superuser', 'last_login', 'date_joined', 'links')

    def get_links(self, obj):
        request = self.context['request']
        username = obj.get_username()
        return{
            'self': reverse('user-detail', kwargs={User.USERNAME_FIELD: username}, request=request)
        }

    def validate(self, attrs):
        #...
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable Django password validation with [`AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/passwords/#module-django.contrib.auth.password_validation) setting. 
But

> Validators aren’t applied at the model level, for example in User.objects.create_user() and create_superuser().

So you need to add validation to the serializer:

```
from django.contrib.auth.password_validation import validate_password

def validate_password(self, value):
    user = self.context['request'].user
    validate_password(password=value, user=user)
```

Comment: Is it possible to add additional validators for the other fields? Or is it maybe more effective to create a model form that you stuff your data in and let that raise validation errors?

Comment: This will not disable all other model level validations if you are talking about it. In case if you need additional validation you can overrider `validate` method or implement `validate_field_name` method inside serializer.

Comment: Oh right, I see, I was rather thinking about copying the validations that the model method .is_valid() does with the data. But hmm...