# DRF how to add to serializer field validation errors?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

In the example below all fields are required. A post request with an empty phone and non matching passwords would result in only the not matching error - presumably because phone comes later when alphabetically sorted.

How do you add to the serializer field errors instead of overriding them?

```
 IN: curl -X POST http://localhost:8000/register/ -d "password=not&password1=matching"

OUT: {"password1":["Passwords do not match."]}

class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password1 = serializers.CharField(write_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('password', 'password1', 'phone')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'password': {'write_only': True},
            'password1': {'write_only': True},
            'phone': {'required': True},
        }

    def create(self, validated_data):
        del validated_data['password1']
        password = validated_data.pop('password', None)
        instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
        if password:
            instance.set_password(password)
        instance.save()
        return instance

    def validate(self, attrs):
        if attrs.get('password') != attrs.get('password1'):
            raise serializers.ValidationError({'password1': ['Passwords do not match.']})
        return attrs
```

Ideally the curl request would output `{"password1":["Passwords do not match."],"phone":["This field is required."]}`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835680/8060120

Comment: @BearBrown in my example the phone field is already required. I'm trying to get it to output both errors instead of just the one. When field validation is run the errors are added to a list and all of the errors are output. In my example just the password error is output. I've now edited my example to clearly display that phone is required.

Comment: `def validate` --> `def validate_password1` based on https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/#writing-custom-validators

Comment: @BearBrown I'm trying to match the value to another field `.validate_<field_name>` only takes one argument so I don't think it's possible

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011256/django-rest-framework-give-serializer-of-default-user-model-validations-that-m use the  `self.context['request'].data.get('password')`

Comment: do you find the solution for your case or still need help? i can start to write the answer, but you should be test it because i have not environment to reproduce it local

Comment: @BearBrown yes, using `self.context['request'].data.get('password')` in `def validate_password1` worked.